# How to set up a calculation including dummy atoms in Dalton Quantum Chemistry Package?

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, multiwfn, dalton

I want to plot a magnetic shielding isosurface around benzene molecule, for that, I prepared a 100 atom grid keeping benzene at the center.

At each grid point there is a dummy atom (X with charge=0.0). Now I want to set a magnetic shielding calculation on this molecular cluster (here by cluster I mean benzene molecule surrounded by 100 dummy atoms). The moment I'm putting up my .mol and .dal file for calculation,

I'm receiving an error that says the basis set doesn't support element with charge 0. Surprisingly I tried other basis sets too but they all ended up with giving same error somehow. I think somehow I have to edit the basis set to incorporate X atom too but I'm clearly lacking the knowledge for same.

I'm attaching all three things, the .mol file, .dal file and the error message I received (the supplied files I'm attaching only contain 9 dummy atoms to keep my question concise).

I suspect if I can plot magnetic shielding isosurfaces directly using Multiwfn but I'm not sure how to do it, as dalton output cannot be converted into .wfn file.

.mol file

```
BASIS
SV+DoubleRydberg(Dunning-Hay)
 Benzene using the SV+DoubleRydberg(Dunning-Hay) Basis set
 Using automatic symmetry detection.
Atomtypes=3
Charge=6.0 Atoms=6
C        1.209256425      0.698164522      0.000000000
C       -1.209256425      0.698164522      0.000000000
C        1.209256425     -0.698164522      0.000000000
C       -1.209256425     -0.698164522      0.000000000
C        0.000000000      1.396329044      0.000000000
C        0.000000000     -1.396329044      0.000000000
Charge=1.0 Atoms=6
H        2.150060899      1.241338238      0.000000000
H       -2.150060899      1.241338238      0.000000000
H        2.150060899     -1.241338238      0.000000000
H       -2.150060899     -1.241338238      0.000000000
H        0.000000000      2.482676477      0.000000000
H        0.000000000     -2.482676477      0.000000000
Charge=0.0 Atoms=9
X       -0.398701210     -0.101689719      1.433969427
X        1.274720770      0.101689719     -1.433969427
X       -1.027638330      0.104867522     -1.478780971
X        1.510572190     -0.096128562      1.355549224
X       -2.802139491     -0.073883936      1.041868412
X        3.318766411     -0.050050408      0.705781827
X        3.026759891      0.080239544     -1.131491501
X       -2.779677451      0.081033995     -1.142694387
X       -4.048782711      0.011916764     -0.168043292
```

.dal file

```
**DALTON INPUT
.RUN PROPERTIES
**WAVE FUNCTIONS
.HF
**PROPERTIES
.SHIELD
.SPIN-S
**END OF DALTON INPUT
```

Error Message is

```
Output from 'grep -n ERROR' :
302: ERROR: Nuclear charge    0 is an unsupported element for basis SV+DoubleRydberg(Dunning-Hay)
303: ERROR: You must choose another basis set, or enter it manually.
307:  --- SEVERE ERROR, PROGRAM WILL BE ABORTED ---
```

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum.

Comment: About plotting wave function from DALTON, take a look [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12053/24).

Comment: Also, I found the following in the DALTON manual (v2020.1, page 247): *The charge of the ion-core is determined by the keyword .ZCMVAL (default: +1), not by a charge specified for X; use Charge=0.0.*

Comment: @Camps Thank you so much for your comment. I already tried this way but unfortunately its not working in my case , so i was really expecting if someone who has already done some dummy atom calculations can share there inputs for me to get a better  idea on where I'm going wrong.